# ignore anything between

Tags: php

I have certain text added to all my files. I want to delete that from my files. The text is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/encryption/index.php" method="POST">



</form>
```

I want to include everything after  but not above it. How can I do that

Comment: How did the text get there? PHP? Template? Include file?

Comment: How do you want to remove it? Using PHP? If not, please remove the PHP tags.

Comment: Why is this tagged `[php4]` and `[php5]`? Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [a PHP DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or [lose your hair with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

I recommend the DOM parser.